# HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported

Tags: javascript, java

I'm trying to make a post with javascript using ajax to a spring controller

```
    $("#crear").click(function () {
        var user = document.getElementById("user").value;
        var client = document.getElementById("client").value;
        var documents = document.getElementById("documents").value;
        if (user==null||client==null||documents==null){
            document.getElementById("error").innerHTML='FALTAN COSASsssssssssss';
            alert('Rellene todo los campos!')
        }
        const data={
            fecha_inicio:'A',
            id:'A',
            fecha_entrega:'A',
            usuario:{
                nombre:user
            },
            cliente: {
                nombre:client
            }
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: urlCrearAlta,
            type: "POST",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {
                // ...
            }

        });
        $.post(urlCrearAlta,JSON.stringify(data),function (data,satus){
            console.log('${data} and status is ${status}')
        });
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML=user+client+documents;
    });
```

and java code

```
@RequestMapping("/altas")
@RestController
public class AltaRestController {

    private AltaController altaController;

    public AltaRestController(AltaController altaController) {
        this.altaController = altaController;
    }
@PostMapping("/create-alta")
    public void createAlta(@RequestBody AltaDTO altaDTO) {
        altaController.createAlta(altaDTO);
    }
```

I'm getting the error Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported]

When i use $.ajax it does not send any request, just when i use $.post it send the request

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be how you are using the `$.post` method. jQuery uses  the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8` contentType on post by default if you don't specify another contentType. Combined with the @RequestBody annotation at backend (which requires `application/json` by default) it results in the seen exception and 415 status code.

The solution to this problem should be fairly easy, just add the correct configuration for the .post method, something like this:

```
$.post({
        url: urlCrearAlta,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
    .done((data, status) => {
          console.log(data, status);
          //do whatever you like with data and status
    });
```

Also, as stated in jQuery documentation [here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), `$.post` is just a shorthand method for `$.ajax`, so if `$.ajax` doesn't work and `$.post` does, there should be something wrong in how you configure the request or how you handle the callbacks methods. The major suspect for me would be the `success` function you specify in the `$.ajax` request, check there is nothing wrong in there, or just use the other callback methods, like `.done`, `.fail` and `.always`

Comment: The request now it seems to be working, but now i have that error: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/altas/create-alta' from origin 'http://localhost:63343' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Error in the browser console. Tanks for you answer

Comment: This happens because now the browser is doing a preflight call to the backend service (option call), you can see it from the network tab. Since your backend service is not responding to that call (or any other request I guess) with the correct `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, the browser blocks the request and you get that exception in console. This behavior is described in full detail [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) and is expected to prevent cross origin requests attacks.

Comment: The problem is that you are serving the front-end application from a different host of the back-end. The exception mentions that you are serving the front-end from http://localhost:63343 while the back-end application is at http://localhost:8080. A simple solution would be to serve the front-end directly from the back-end application, or to enable CORS in the spring application (follow the instructions [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/) to see how)